# trigger to insert value into a parent table when inserting into the child table

Tags: mysql, triggers, mysql-error-1452

I have two tables with the construction below.  When I try to add to the books table I get an error that I cannot add or update a child row which I expected.  I was hoping that a trigger could be created to add the publisher name to the publisher table before adding to the books table.

This is my first time working with a trigger and I am not sure what I am doing wrong and I can't find an example.

```
create table publishers
    (name varchar(25) not null, 
    address varchar(55), 
    phone varchar(12),
    PRIMARY KEY(name)
    ) ENGINE = INNODB;

create table books
    (book_id int(4) not null auto_increment, 
    title varchar(40), 
    publisher_name varchar(25),
    primary key (book_id),
    foreign key (publisher_name) references publishers(name) ON UPDATE CASCADE ON DELETE CASCADE 
    ) ENGINE=INNODB;
```

and the trigger I am trying to create:

```
DELIMITER ///
CREATE TRIGGER add_publisher BEFORE insert ON books
    FOR EACH ROW
    BEGIN
    INSERT INTO publishers(name) values (books.pubisher_name);
END;
///

DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: A stored procedure will be a better choice for this I think...

Comment: Question, what is the version of you mysql ?

Comment: @Blag I am using 5.1 I believe.

Comment: Try what Jiri give you, if it still fail, then you probably are against a bug patched on the 5.7 about check of constraint before `BEFORE` Trigger (but this patch may be only for `NOT NULL` constrain, I don't know for FK...)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace **books.publisher_name** for **NEW.publisher_name**.

```
    DELIMITER ///
    CREATE TRIGGER add_publisher BEFORE insert ON books
        FOR EACH ROW
        BEGIN
        INSERT INTO publishers(name) values (NEW.publisher_name);
    END;
    ///
DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: Thank you.  I thought I had tried this.  I must have spelled something wrong.